# How to conditionally combine a RegionPlot3D with a ContourPlot3D inside a Manipulate?

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, conditional, graphics

I know how to combine a `RegionPlot3D` and a `ContourPlot3D`, which I did (see below for details on the code I'm referring to) with

```
Show[regionPlot,contourPlot]
```

What I want is to make the ContourPlot appear and disappear switching a checkbox in the `Manipulate` controls.
I actually managed to do this using

```
If[showQPlane,Show[regionPlot,contourPlot],regionPlot]
```

but I feel that this is not the optimal, cleaner solution.

> Is it possible to conditionally append one (or more) argument(s) to the `Show`, with something like

```
Show[regionPlot,If[showQPlane,contourPlot]]
```

> which however unfortunately does not work?

I would also like the contourPlot to not be calculated at all when not shown, if possible.

---

Here is the code I ended up using following the tips by LLIAMnYP and Kuba, in which I also added an option to display a 2D `RegionPlot` of the intersection of the `RegionPlot3D` and the `ContourPlot3D`:

```
U[Q_, q_] := (Q^2 + q^2 + 2 q Q^2 - 2/3 q^3)/2
Manipulate[
 regionPlot := RegionPlot3D[
   If[! invertRegion,
    p^2/2 + U[Q, q] <= energy,
    p^2/2 + U[Q, q] >= energy
    ],
   {p, -regionSize, regionSize},
   {q, -regionSize, regionSize},
   {Q, -regionSize, regionSize},
   AxesLabel -> {"p", "q", "Q"},
   PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
   PlotRange -> {{-regionSize, regionSize}, {-regionSize, 
      regionSize}, {-regionSize, regionSize}},
   ImageSize -> 800,
   PlotPoints -> plotPoints,
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{p, q, Q}, Q - coordQPlane]},
   Mesh -> {{0}},
   MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, Thick],
   RotationAction -> "Clip"
   ];
 If[showQPlane,
  contourPlot := ContourPlot3D[
    Q == coordQPlane,
    {p, -regionSize, regionSize},
    {q, -regionSize, regionSize},
    {Q, -regionSize, regionSize},
    Mesh -> None,
    ContourStyle -> Purple,
    RotationAction -> "Clip"
    ]
  ];
 If[showSlice,
  slicePlot := RegionPlot[
    If[! invertRegion,
     p^2/2 + U[coordQPlane, q] <= energy,
     p^2/2 + U[coordQPlane, q] >= energy
     ],
    {p, -regionSize, regionSize},
    {q, -regionSize, regionSize},
    AxesLabel -> {"p", "q"},
    PerformanceGoal -> "Quality",
    PlotRange -> {{-regionSize, regionSize}, {-regionSize, 
       regionSize}},
    ImageSize -> 800,
    PlotPoints -> plotPoints
    ]
  ];
 Dynamic@Row[{
    Dynamic@Show[
      (Pick[
         HoldComplete@{regionPlot, contourPlot},
         {{True, showQPlane}}
         ])[[1]]
      ],
    If[showSlice,
     slicePlot,
     Sequence[]
     ]
    }],
 {{energy, 0.15, "Energy"}, 0., 10., 0.01, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{regionSize, 4., "Region Size:"}, 1., 100., 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{plotPoints, 20, "Plot Points"}, 10, 100, 1, Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{coordQPlane, 0., "Q Plane"}, -regionSize, regionSize, 0.1, 
  Appearance -> "Open"},
 {{showQPlane, True, "Show Plane"}, {False, True}},
 {{showSlice, False, "Show Slice"}, {False, True}},
 {{invertRegion, False, "Invert region"}, {False, True}},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False,
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

And here is a snapshot of the output:
[image]

Comment: @Kuba that's perfect, I didn't really think of using an empty list inside the list given to Show, thanks! Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Instead of `If`s, I prefer this: `Show[Pick[{regionPlot, contourPlot}, {True, showQPlane}]]`. Still working on suppresing evaluation though.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP which evaluation?

Comment: @Kuba the one that doesn't happen because `If` has `HoldRest` :)

Comment: @glance thanks for the accept, though I don't think it's a good idea to remove the original code. I found it in the revision history as I wanted to toy around with it some more, but the problem may not be clear anymore to people, who read the question in the future.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP Oh, I thought something should be fixed in my answer. Well, I guess one should do whatever is more readable/clean for him/her if it works . I'm not using `If`s to much, but I'm not using `Manipulate` at all for complex cases either.

Comment: What's your definition of `U`?

Comment: @ChipHurst sorry, I forgot to include it in the last edit. It's there now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in my comment, I feel, it's cleaner to use

```
Show[(Pick[HoldComplete[{regionPlot, contourPlot}], {{True, showQPlane}}])[[1]]]
```

Additionaly I use `SetDelayed` in the definition of `contourPlot` to prevent evaluation at definition and `HoldComplete` makes sure that first `Pick` is run, and only then what's left is evaluated. `[[1]]` strips the result of `Pick` of the `HoldComplete` head.

By the way, there's several ways to use `If` and your initial construct:

```
Show[regionPlot,If[showQPlane,contourPlot,Unevaluated@Sequence[]]]
```

You just needed to pass a proper return for the `False` condition, otherwise the return is `Null` and that is not a `Graphics` object.

This is, of course, easily extendable to multiple `If`s:

```
Show[regionPlot,If[showQ1,plot1,Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
                If[showQ2,plot2,Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
                If[showQ3,plot3,Unevaluated@Sequence[]],
                ...
                If[showQn,plotn,Unevaluated@Sequence[]]
    ]
```

Because `If` has the attribute `HoldRest`, when contourPlot isn't shown, it is accordingly not evaluated. You can check, whether or not something is being evaluated by making the definition a compound expression, e.g:

```
contourPlot := (Print["Evaluating"];ContourPlot[...]);
```

Then, for example

```
Pick[{regionPlot, contourPlot}, {True, False}]
```

> `Evaluating`, >picture of only `regionPlot` but `contourPlot` still got evaluated<

But

```
Show[(Pick[HoldComplete[{regionPlot, contourPlot}], {{True, showQPlane}}])[[1]]]
```

> just `regionPlot`, no evaluating message.

And the same goes for

```
Show[regionPlot, If[False, contourPlot, Unevaluated@Sequence[]]]
```

Comment: Very interesting, thanks a lot for sharing. Indeed I like these methods even more than the one proposed by Kuba.

Answer (score 1):

This is a minimal example of how to do something like this:

```
Manipulate[ 
  plot1 = Graphics3D@Sphere[{0, 0, 0}, 1.3]; 
  If[x, Print@"Calculating plot2"; plot2 = Graphics3D@Cylinder[]]; 

  Show[{plot1, If[x, plot2, {}]}]
  , 
  {{x, True}, {True, False}}
]
```

Body of the `Manipulate` is inside `Dynamic` so if you want to be able to control what is sent to evaluation from there I suggest to read `AdvancedDynamicFunctionality` tutorial. Especially the section `Nesting Dynamic`.

Comment: I've read the tutorial you suggested, and tried to implement the advices. I've found however some difficulties in fully enclosing the manipulated variables in nested dynamics. For example in the code I included I also tried to wrap with `Dynamic` the variable `coordQPlane` to avoid the whole RegionPlot3D being redrawn when moving the Plane, but it doesn't seem to work. Do you have any tip on why is this so?